# @content_type in paperclip gem returns different value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

In windows, I get:

```
@content_type="application/octet-stream"
```

Full trace:

```
"attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f7bb52becc8 @original_filename="ms_document.doc", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[attachments_attributes][0][attachment]\"; filename=\"doc\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160108-8859-x51qhj>>}}}
```

In Linux I get:

```
@content_type="application/msword"
```

Full trace:

```
"attachments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f7bb5d585d0 @original_filename="ms_document.doc", @content_type="application/msword", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[attachments_attributes][0][attachment]\"; filename=\"doc.doc\"\r\nContent-Type: application/msword\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160108-8859-9m1xgv>>}}}
```

The question is, why I received different @content_type while I'm uploading the same file but only different OS.

I'm using:

1. rails 3
2. paperclip '4.3.2'

Comment: This is also experienced with CSVs for example. You can even get different content types for Windows machines when Excel is installed and isn't installed. So if you are configuring paperclip to do content-type validation or protect against content-type spoofing, you'll need to handle all these `text/plain`, `text/csv`, `text/comma-separated-values`, `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP specification [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7) states that

> When an entity-body is included with a message, the data type of that body is determined via the header fields Content-Type and Content- Encoding. These define a two-layer, ordered encoding model:
>
> entity-body := Content-Encoding( Content-Type( data ) ) Content-Type
>   specifies the media type of the underlying data. Content-Encoding may
>   be used to indicate any additional content codings applied to the
>   data, usually for the purpose of data compression, that are a property
>   of the requested resource. There is no default encoding.
>
> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
>   Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and
>   only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
>   recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
>   content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
>   resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
>   treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

In your case, this might have happened, beacuse the server on which the file had been sent/uploaded wasn't able to determine the type of file, because the browser might have not set the Content-Type in HTTP message when sending the file.

It depends on which browser and OS you are using. Browser on windows might be not setting the content type.